# How to pass RAML-trait-parameters for enum values?

Tags: rest, api, parameters, traits, raml

I do have a RAML with several traits and recourceTypes. I do use the parameters there quite frequently. However, for one case I can't get it working.

Let's assume the following trait, named "testTrait":

```
#%RAML 1.0 Trait

queryParameters:
  s:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
      enum: <<parameterEnum>>
```

The **enum: parameterEnum>>** is the important part here.

This is used, beside many other working traits (wich I don't mention here to keep the example simple), in the following resourceType (which shouldn't have an influence on the issue, as I do simply pass the parameter through).

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

...

resourceTypes:
  item-readonly:
      get:
        description: |
          <<descriptionGet>>
        is: [
          testTrait: {
            parameterEnum: <<parameterEnum>>
            }]
```

In this way, the trait "testTrait" is used in the API definition:

```
#%RAML 1.0

...

/services/:
  /testServiceA/:
    type:
      ResourceTypes.item-readonly:
        descriptionGet: A service to test Enum parameters in RAML.
        parameterEnum: ???
```

**What should I fill in for the '???' ?**

I tested:

```
parameterEnum: [key,name]
```

Which resulted in error: "Property 'parameterEnum' must be a string"
Changing to:

```
parameterEnum: "[key,name]"
```

leads to the error: "'enum' facet value must be defined by array"

I'm stuck at this point. For other trait-parameters (used in traits for description, for types, etc.) I didn't have any problem.
Any advice to point me to the right solution is appreciated.

I use Atom with API Workbench for the API definition.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes, it does not work. The only way seems to be: enum: [<<parameterEnum1>>, <<parameterEnum2>>] (yes, I know...). You could add an issue for this.